# How to execute git log on windows cmd?

Tags: windows, git, bash, batch-file

I have the following command:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:'<li>%h %ci %d %s</li>' > changelog.html
```

That saves the git log to the changelog.html file. When i execute it through git bash, it works fine, but when i put this code in a .bat file and run it, i get the following error:

`The system could not find the specified file`

I think it's caused by the quotes on the format parameter, but i don't know how to solve the problem... Is there a way to escape the quotes maybe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside a Windows batch file, you have to:

- *double* `%` chars. for them to be taken as *literals*
- use *double* quotes to protect embedded whitespace or other special chars. such as `>`:

```sh
git log --pretty=tformat:"<li>%%h %%ci %%d %%s</li>" > changelog.html
```

- Generally, you can also use `^` to escape *individual* characters in an *unquoted* string (e.g., `^%` to represent literal `%`, or  `^|` to represent literal `|`), but *that wouldn't work here*, because of the following **caveat**:
  You *cannot* use `^` to escape a *space* character in order to form a *single* argument with embedded whitespace; for instance, `foo^ bar` is still split into *2* arguments, `foo` and `bar`.

---

Some **background** for readers from the **Unix world**:

- There is **no equivalent to a POSIX-like shell's *single*-quoted strings** (strings to be taken *literally*, with no expansions taking place) in the Windows batch language.

  - ***Single* quotes generally have no special meaning in the Windows batch language** (except in certain special contexts, such as a `for` loop) - they **canNOT be used to delimit a string with embedded whitespace.**
- Thus, analogous to how you have to escape `$`in double-quoted bash strings as `\$` to prevent expansion, you have to **escape `%` as `%%` in double-quoted strings to prevent expansions** in batch files, given that an identifier enclosed in `%` chars. (e.g., `%PATH%`) signifies a *variable reference* to expand.

  - The curious thing is that an *interactive* `cmd.exe` prompt *doesn't* require escaping of `%`, whereas batch files do. <sup>More specifically, `%` chars. in an interactive command line are treated as literals, *unless* they are part of a variable reference to an *existing* variable (e.g., `%windir%`), in which case expansion does take place. This oddity is the reason that a `for` loop must be written as `for %i in ...` (*one* `%`) on the command line, and as `for %%i in ...` (*two* `%`) in a batch file.</sup>
- A **caveat re passing double-quoted strings to *batch* files**: When passing an argument enclosed in double quotes, the **double quotes are *included* in the argument value**; the **`~` parameter modifier can be used to strip them**; e.g., `%~1` returns the 1st argument *without* double quotes (if any).
- Finally, the **counterpart of `\`-escaping *individual* characters in an *unquoted* string** in a POSIX shell is **`^`-escaping**, but, as stated, **`^` cannot be used to escape a space in order to form a single argument with embedded whitespace.**